# Scan screen for color

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel, screen-capture, scanning

I would like, in Java, to scan the screen for a particular color.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you need this for? Just curious.

Comment: Thought so. This was one of the first approaches used for a game I used to play. The textures could be swapped around for with ones that had solid colour and an external program would scan the screen. It became obsolete when someone found a way to access variables directly in memory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
    // ...

    int color = image.getRGB(x, y);

    int  red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    int  green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
    int  blue = color & 0x000000ff;
    // ...
```

Comment: @Reuben Mallaby The joys of cut and paste. color, you are finding the r g and b values from the color. I updated my post

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - To fix the Robot

Comment: Romain, "_why_" refers to you swallowing the exception instead of doing an `e.printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use Java.awt.Robot to take a screenshot as an Image and proceess that.