# How to scan the screen for a specific color/image in java?

Tags: java, colors

I need to scan the screen for a specific image/color and return an x and y coordinate for where that color occurs.

I know that this will probably include taking a screenshot using the Robot class, but have no idea how to then scan that image appropriately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - scan screen for color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033517/java-scan-screen-for-color)

Answer (score 2):

If you take a screenshot with the Robot class, you get an object of the class BuffereImage. Then you for loop the width and height (getWidth(), getHeight()). With the getRGB() method you can extract the RGB value of the pixel. If it matches, you can store it in aan collection or array.

```
BufferedImage img = ...
int matchColor = Color.RED.getRGB();
int h = img.getHeight();
int w = img.getWidth();
Set<Point> points = new HashSet<Point>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < w ; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < h ; j++) {
        if(img.getRGB(i, j) == matchColor) {
            points.add(new Point(i, j));
        }
    }
}

...
```